# Роль методов BeginEdit() и EndEdit(). А так же AcceptChanges()

Tags: c#, база-данных, ado.net

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем сакральный смысл методов `BeginEdit()` и `EndEdit()` в Ado.Net автономный. Прочитал Троелсена и MSDN и так и не врубился зачем они нужны. Данные в базе прекрасно редактируются и без них, например так
`ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1] = "bla"`. Что касается `AcceptChanges()`, тоже вот не могу понять, он фиксирует изменения в `dataset, rows, columns etc...`, но не могу понять в каких случаях его применять. В своем коде, я после окончания внесения / изменения данных в БД пишу такой код:

```
SqlCommandBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDA);
sqlDA.Update(ds);
```

и , собственно все изменения тогда фиксируются и отправляются в "физическую" БД, но каков смысл использовать данный метод в коде до отправки изменений в БД не пойму. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Что не понятного из того что сказано в MSDN по этому поводу?

Comment: Все что не понятно я написал в вопросе выше

Comment: Use the BeginEdit method to put a DataRow into edit mode. In this mode, events are temporarily suspended, letting the user make changes to more than one row without triggering validation rules. For example, if you must make sure that the value of the column for a total amount is equal to the values for the debit and credit columns in a row, you can put each row into edit mode to suspend the validation of the row values until the user tries to commit the values.

Comment: Написано же что события не генерируются, позволяет менять без преждевременной валидации и так далее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала надо обратить внимание на тот факт, что ячейка объекта `DataRow` может хранить больше одного значения. И получить эти значения можно используя одно из значений перечисления [DataRowVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datarowversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Создадим таблицу и загрузим данные:

```
DataTable table1 = new DataTable("Table1");

table1.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32));
table1.Columns.Add("value", typeof(String));

table1.LoadDataRow(new Object[] { 0, "zero" }, true);

DataRow dr = table1.Rows[0];
```

Таким образом, посмотрев на перечисление `DataRowVersion` мы видим, что функционал `DataRow` позволяет хранить оригинальное и модифицированное  значения одновременно.

```
Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Original]);
Console.WriteLine("Current:  {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Current]);
```

Вывод на консоль:

> Original: zero
>   Current:  zero

Если текущее значение ячейки изменить на другое значение, то `DataRow` будет хранить оба этих значения:

```
dr[1] = "one";

Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Original]);
Console.WriteLine("Current:  {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Current]);
```

Вывод на консоль:

> Original: zero
>   Current:  one

Метод [DataRow.BeginEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datarow.beginedit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) позволяет вступить в игру третьему значению, которое может храниться в ячейке объекта `DataRow`. Это значение `Proposed` и оно позволяет изменять текущее значение на время редактирования:

```
dr.BeginEdit();

dr[1] = "two";

Console.WriteLine(dr[1, DataRowVersion.Original]);
Console.WriteLine(dr[1, DataRowVersion.Current]);
Console.WriteLine(dr[1, DataRowVersion.Proposed]);
```

Вывод на консоль:

> Original: zero
>   Current:  one
>   Proposed: two

Далее метод [DataRow.EndEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datarow.endedit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) нужно рассматривать в паре с методом [DataRow.CancelEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datarow.endedit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Метод `EndEdit` позволят завершить режим редактирования и заменяет текущее значение ячейки редактируемым:

```
dr.EndEdit();

Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Original]);
Console.WriteLine("Current:  {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Current]);
```

Вывод на консоль:

> Original: zero
>   Current:  two

Метод `CancelEdit` просто закроет режим редактирования и оставит текущее значение ячейки неизменным:

```
dr.BeginEdit();

dr[1] = "tree";
Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Original]);
Console.WriteLine("Current:  {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Current]);
Console.WriteLine("Proposed: {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Proposed]);

dr.CancelEdit();

Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Original]);
Console.WriteLine("Current:  {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Current]);
```

Вывод на консоль:

> Original: zero
>   Current:  two
>    Proposed: tree
>
> Original: zero
>   Current:  two

Метод же [DataRow.AcceptChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datarow.acceptchanges%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) нужно расматривать в паре с [DataRow.RejectChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datarow.rejectchanges%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Метод `AcceptChanges` фиксирует изменения, т.е. он заменяет оригинальные значения ячеек `DataRow` текущим значениям:

```
dr.AcceptChanges();

Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Original]);
Console.WriteLine("Current:  {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Current]);
```

Вывод на консоль:

> Original: two
>   Current:  two

Таким образом, метод `AcceptChanges` фиксирует изменение приводя `DataRow` в состояние исходное, т.е. последующие изменения будут сделан относительно зафиксированного.

Метод `RejectChanges` откатывает все изменения в значениях ячеек DataRow, приводя все ячейки в предыдущие зафиксированные значения.

```
dr[1] = "four";

Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Original]);
Console.WriteLine("Current:  {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Current]);

dr.RejectChanges();

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Original]);
Console.WriteLine("Current:  {0}", dr[1, DataRowVersion.Current]);
```

Вывод на консоль:

> Original: two
>   Current:  four
>
> Original: two
>   Current:  two

Для чего это нужно? Для создания режимов редактирования с возможностью фиксации или отката изменяемых значений.

Также методы BeginEdit и EndEdit/CabcelEdit участвуют в режиме блокировки событий изменений на время редактирования.

Замечание. Здесь представлены не все возможные состояния значений ячеек `DataRow`, так как они также могут завить от состояния самого DataRow, указанного в [RowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).